# Loading env variables in React using Vite

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, fetch-api, api-key, dotenv

I have a React project where I want to fetch a weather API. When I use the API without without storing them in a variable it works, bt if I put them in dotenv and use the `import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY;` it gives me an error message that API Key is disabled.

This is my React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

// dotenv.config()

const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY;

const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Key", apiKey);

const requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?Key=${apiKey}&q=Jos&days=5`,requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

This is my env:

```
VITE_API_KEY=XXX
```

Comment: Does your env files is called `.env` or `env`?

Comment: it is called .env

Comment: Is it placed on the same level as `package.json`?

Comment: Thank you. You made me realized I placed my env file in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it. The error I made was putting my env file in my src folder. I deleted it and created a new env file outside of my src folder and it worked.